# Playing video in Qt (on a Mac)

Tags: macos, qt, video, movie, avi

This question arises out of a combination of this being my first time working with video and unfamiliarity with Macs.  Basically I'm finding it difficult to figure out how to play a video (within a QWidget, or otherwise) using any standard format, e.g. avi, mpeg, mov, etc.  In particular,

- `QMovie::supportedFormats()` gives me only .gif and .mng, but I need to use standard formats.  Is there a way to increase the number of supported formats?
- `Phonon` requires the presence of a '[backend](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-overview.html)' which the user has to implement himself.  I looked to see if I could somehow do this with Quicktime, but I couldn't get the application to launch--and anyway I didn't really see how to do that.  Also, `Phonon` looks pretty heavyweight, I'd like to avoid it if I could.
- While there are plenty of avi (et al.) players floating around on the web, I think it's probably unlikely I'd be able to use them--I need to start, stop, and change the playback speed of videos programmatically i.e. through my C++ program.

I'm not sure why this should be so hard--working with images in Qt is a snap by comparison.  So: What's a good way to play videos from within a C++/Qt program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Stop** what you are doing right now: *Phonon is the past*, **[Qt Mobility](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility/) is the future**.

After you download, compile and install Qt Mobility, check the examples: **videowidget** and **videographicsitem**, located at: `qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.2.0/examples/`

They pretty much answer all your questions.

Comment: That's funny, I had just assumed from the title that Qt Mobility was an API for handheld devices.  But it's suited to desktop applications too?